# What causes the error "Unable to obtain LocalDate" from TemporalAccessor?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
var inFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa");
var outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        
var parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(s, inFormatter);
var outDate = parsedDate.format(outFormatter);
return outDate;
```

Given input "07:05:45PM" I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '07:05:45PM' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 19:05:45 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

I'm confused because the value it resolved to... is what I'd expect it to resolve to. So why the error? Using SimpleDateFormat instead, this code works fine.

Comment: You input is a date value, it's a time value. Also, beware, different locales format things like `AM`/`PM` differently.  The following works for me: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").format(LocalTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa", Locale.US)));`

Comment: As commented, your `LocalDate` should have been `LocalTime`. Voting to close as a typo.